# How to deal with multiple threads in perl which turn into zombie

Tags: multithreading, perl

It seems using pipe in threads might cause the threads turn into zombie. In fact the commands in the pipe truned into zombie, not the threads. This does not happen very time which is annoying since it's hard to find out the real problem. How to deal with this issue? What causes these? Was it related to the pipe? How to avoid this?

The following is the codes that creates sample files.

```
#buildTest.pl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub generateChrs{
    my ($outfile, $num, $range)=@_;
    open OUTPUT, "|gzip>$outfile";
    my @set=('A','T','C','G');
    my $cnt=0;
    while ($cnt<$num) {
        # body...
        my $pos=int(rand($range));
        my $str = join '' => map $set[rand @set], 1 .. rand(200)+1;
        print OUTPUT "$cnt\t$pos\t$str\n";
        $cnt++
    }
    close OUTPUT;
}

sub new_chr{
    my @chrs=1..22;
    push @chrs,("X","Y","M", "Other");
    return @chrs;
}

for my $chr (&new_chr){
    generateChrs("$chr.gz",50000,100000)
}
```

The following codes will create zombie threads occasionally. Reason or trigger remains unknown.

```
#paralRM.pl
use strict;
use threads;
use Thread::Semaphore;
my $s = Thread::Semaphore->new(10);

sub rmDup{
    my $reads_chr=$_[0];
    print "remove duplication $reads_chr START TIME: ",`date`;
    return 0 if(!-s $reads_chr);

    my $dup_removed_file=$reads_chr . ".rm.gz";
    $s->down();
    open READCHR, "gunzip -c $reads_chr |sort -n -k2 |" or die "Error: cannot open $reads_chr";
    open OUTPUT, "|sort -k4 -n|gzip>$dup_removed_file";

    my ($last_id, $last_pos, $last_reads)=split('\t',<READCHR>);
    chomp($last_reads);
    my $last_length=length($last_reads);
    my $removalCnts=0;

    while (<READCHR>) {
        chomp;
        my @line=split('\t',$_);
        my ($id, $pos, $reads)=@line;
        my $cur_length=length($reads);
        if($last_pos==$pos){
            #may dup
            if($cur_length>$last_length){
                ($last_id, $last_pos, $last_reads)=@line;
                $last_length=$cur_length;
            }
            $removalCnts++;
            next;
        }else{
            #not dup
        }
        print OUTPUT join("\t",$last_id, $last_pos, $last_reads, $last_length, "\n");
        ($last_id, $last_pos, $last_reads)=@line;
        $last_length=$cur_length;
    }

    print OUTPUT join("\t",$last_id, $last_pos, $last_reads, $last_length, "\n");
    close OUTPUT;
    close READCHR;
    $s->up();
    print "remove duplication $reads_chr END TIME: ",`date`;
    #unlink("$reads_chr")
    return $removalCnts;
}


sub parallelRMdup{
    my @chrs=@_;
    my %jobs;
    my @removedCnts;
    my @processing;

    foreach my $chr(@chrs){
        while (${$s}<=0) {
            # body...
            sleep 10;
        }
        $jobs{$chr}=async {
            return &rmDup("$chr.gz")
            }
        push @processing, $chr;
    };

    #wait for all threads finish
    foreach my $chr(@processing){
        push @removedCnts, $jobs{$chr}->join();
    }
}

sub new_chr{
    my @chrs=1..22;
    push @chrs,("X","Y","M", "Other");
    return @chrs;
}

&parallelRMdup(&new_chr);
```

Comment: Do all your threads report a sensible start and end time? But I can't see anything obviously wrong with your code that could leave threads unjoined. However, there are some bad practices: ① are you missing a semicolon after the `async` block? ② Don't do busy waiting when spawning the threads. And don't dereference the Semaphore object. Instead, you could `down` the semaphore before spawing, but `up` it at the end of the thread → much better. ③ You should programmatically assert that all `@chrs` are unique, else you'll only join the last thread for a `$chr`.

Comment: The zombie was created in the pipe(sort, gzip etc.). Thanks for your advice. I learned a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As the comments on your originating post suggest - there isn't anything obviously wrong with your code here. What might be helpful to understand is what a `zombie` process is.

Specifically - it's a spawned process (by your `open`) which has exited, but the parent hasn't collected it's return code yet.

For short running code, that's not all that significant - when your main program exits, the zombies will 'reparent' to `init` which will clean them up automatically.

For longer running, you can use `waitpid` to clean them up and collect return codes.

Now in this specific case - I can't see a specific problem, but I would *guess* it's to do with how you're opening your filehandles. The downside of opening filehandles like you are, is that they're globally scoped - and that's just generally bad news when you're doing thready things.

I would imagine if you changed your `open` calls to:

```
my $pid = open ( my $exec_fh, "|-", "executable" );
```

And then called `waitpid` on that `$pid` following your `close` then your zombies would finish. Test the return from `waitpid` to get an idea of which of your execs has errored (if any), which should help you track down why.

Alternatively - set `$SIG{CHLD} = "IGNORE";` which will mean you - effectively - tell your child processes to 'just go away immediately' - but you won't be able to get a return code from them if they die.